# Rename directories with fileutils in Ruby

Tags: ruby, directory, mv

While renaming a set of directories I end up wit ha strange error
I call FileUtils with success for many folders, and subfolders.

But when I try it on subsubfolder I get a strange error.
Just before executing FileUtils.mv I print src and dest to be sure that they represent something ok and this is what I end up with :

```
change Folder_From_Archive/Student1/Ex1/
to Folder_From_Archive/Student1/ex1/

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:505:in `rename': Invalid argument - Folder_From_Archive/Student/Ex1/ or Folder_From_Archive/Student/ex1/Ex1 (Errno::EINVAL)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:505:in `mv'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:1396:in `fu_each_src_dest'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:1410:in `fu_each_src_dest0'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:1394:in `fu_each_src_dest'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:494:in `mv'
from unzip_all.rb:51:in `verify_submissions'
from unzip_all.rb:44:in `each'
from unzip_all.rb:44:in `verify_submissions'
from unzip_all.rb:40:in `each'
from unzip_all.rb:40:in `verify_submissions'
from unzip_all.rb:80
```

What is funny is that I have many Student folder that I rename sucessfully with the same command.

EDIT : Following the questions.
I try to move the folder path/Ex1 to path/ex1
I want to rename Ex1 to ex1 basically, so before running it ex1 does not exist.

Here are the result of ls for the folders that I can rename
    drwxr-xr-x
And here it is for the folder Ex1 that I can't rename
    drwxr-----

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to be sure what is going wrong since you didn't post your code, but the error message clearly shows that you are trying to move the Ex1 directory into the ex1 directory, which doesn't exist.  You need to fix your call to `File.mv`.

Answer (score 0):

can youcheck with 'ls -ld' what the permissions and ownership of those folders are, and post them here? e.g. the enclosing folder and the folder causing the error